# Какой инструмент выбрать для описания программы в диаграммах?

Tags: c++

Хочу полностью понять, как работает некая программа, но в голове все тяжело уложить, и потом что-то забудется. Так что хочу описать программный код в диаграммах для себя, то есть кто кого вызывает или просто что происходит в определенном участке кода, чтобы в итоге получить полную картину происходящего. Какой есть хороший инструмент для этого? Или обычный UML подойдет? В общем, мне не нужна автоматическая генерация по заголовкам или коду, мне просто нужен расширенный функционал по созданию диаграмм вручную.

Comment: Карандаш и листик? Лучшего не встречал:)

Comment: UML для этого и создан, в общем-то.

Comment: ArgoUML - насколько я понимаю, лучшее из бесплатных.

Comment: Самое лучшее средство понять что делает программа - это понять предметную область для которой она создавалась. Для потоков данных и архитектуры БД неплохо использовать ERwin Data Modeler - если уж софт так мего глобален.
Когда вы осознаете в голове потоки информации, тогда вам сразу запомнятся функции и процедуры программы, независимо от их сложности, даже если вы не понимаете тот или иной кусок кода - вы будете знать для чего он...
Можно конечно следом и UML всяческие писать...

Answer (score 1):

Анализатор создаст для вас всего лишь одну диаграмму - статичскую диаграмму классов. А что бы понять как программа функционирует вам понадобятся динамические диаграммы. Тут их лучше всего рисовать самому. Я использую UML. Но замечу это все же язык. И его нужно учить и практиковать. Из своего опыта замечу, что использовать какой-то тул для рисования диаграмм, что бы понять как работает программа, это потеря времени. Листик, карандаш и стирка - будут быстрее. При условии, что вы знаете хотя бы азы UML. Если вы не сильны в UML, то при изучении прогарммы достаточно будет нарисовать диаграмму объектов (не классов, именно объектов) и диаграмму коммуникации.